# Optimization run assistance

Tags: c++, hashtable, hash, hashcode

I am running the optimisation of two sets of data against each other and am after some assistance as to looking up settings of the run based on the calculated results. I'll explain....

I run 2 data lines against each other (think graph lines) - Line A and Line B. These lines have crossing points - upward and downward based on the direction of each line.e.g. Line A is going up and Line B is going down is an 'Upwards cross' and Line A going down and Line B going up is a 'Downward cross'.The program calculates financial analysis.

I analyze the crossing points and gain a resultant 'Rank' from the analysis based on a set of rules. The rank is a single integer.

Line A has a number of settings for the optimisation run e.g. Window 1 from a value of 10 to 20 and window 2 at a value of 30 to 40. Line B also has settings.

When I run the optimisation I iterate through the parameters available for each line and calculate the rank. The result of the optimisation run is a list of the ranks which is the size of the number of permutations avaliable.

So my question is this:

What is the best way to look up the line settings from the calculated rank using a position (index) in the rank list. The optimisation settings used to create the run will be stored for that rank run and can be used for the look-up.

I also will be adding additional parameters in the future to the system for the line so I want the program to take into account additional future line settings without affecting any rank files created previous to adding the new parameter.

In addition to that I want to be able to find out an index based on a particular setting included in the optimisation run (the reverse look-up of the previous method).

I want to avoid versioning for backward compatability if at all possible so that the lookup algorithm will be self-sufficient.

Is a hash table suitable for this purpose or do you have any implementation techniques that would fit better? Do you have any examples of this type of operation in action in C++?

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a bunch of associated data (settings + rank), on which you would like to be able to perform lookups with different key types.  If so, then [*Boost.MultiIndex*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html) sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Sort of, I have an initial set of settings like this:
LineA: Window 1 from 10 to 20 Window 2 from 30 to 40
LineB: Window 3 from 40 to 50 Window 4 from 50 to 60
This results in an optimisation run that has 10*10*10*10 permutations. I get a list from that run of ranks for each of the permutations.

I save the optimisation settings once somewhere so I have access to window1,window2 etc... for that run so I need to use those initial settings along with the index to find out the settings for the position.